# In Visual Force Page not able to make Account Id inlineEditable

Tags: apex, visualforce, inlineeditsupport

I have a Visualforce page which displays Account Id and User First Name with  "inlineEditSupport"

Visulaforce Page :

```
 <apex:dataList value="{!resobj}" var="a">
  <apex:inLineEditSupport event="ondblclick" showOnEdit="Update"/>
      <apex:outputField id="OrgId" value="{!a.BAccounts.Id}"/>
      <apex:outputField id="name" value="{!a.usr.FirstName}"/>
  </apex:dataList>
  <apex:commandButton value="GetData" id="submit" action="{!getdata}"/>
```

After get the result iam able to edit firstname but not able to edit Account Id.
why I am not able to edit Id in the VisualForce Page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The editability will depend on the type of the relationship.

If it is "Master-Detail Relationship" without "Allow reparenting" the field will not be editable because the objects are tightly tied together in terms of things like ownership and cascading deletes.

But if it is "Lookup Relationship" (or "Master-Detail Relationship" with "Allow reparenting") it should be editable.

Answer (score 2):

Account ID is always a read only field. You cannot edit it. If you want to change the account Id you have to load the page again with that particular Account.